# Can't store a new row - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

My clients table and users table are child tables of my businesses table. So both the clients and users table contain a business_id column that refers to the id column of the businesses table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clients', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('business_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('business_id')->references('id')->on('businesses');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        Etc…
```

I am able to store a new user, it works fine, but I keep getting this error when trying to store a new row into my clients table :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`laravel`.`clients`, CONSTRAINT `clients_business_id_foreign` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`business_id`)

Client.php model

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['business_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'];

/**
 * Business where this user works.
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function businesses()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Business');
}
```

Business.php model

```
/**
 * Clients that use this business.
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */ 
public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Client','business_id');
}
```

ClientsController.php

```
public function store(ClientsRequest $request)
{
    var_dump(Auth::user()->business_id);

    $clientinfo = Request::all();

    Client::create($clientinfo);

    $client = new Client;
    $client->business_id = Auth::user()->business_id;
    $client->first_name = $clientinfo['first_name'];
    $client->last_name = $clientinfo['last_name'];

    //$client->save();
    $business->clients()->save($client);

    $last_inserted_id = $data->id;

    return redirect('clients/'.$last_inserted_id.'/edit');
```

The only thing I’m not sure is the way I’m retrieving the business_id (from the users table), via Auth. When I var_dump that value, I get :

```
string(1) "7"
```

I know the id value is 7 in my businesses table, that’s what I’m looking for, but not sure if it should be converted to integer.

And, not sure if I have to save using :

```
 $client->save();
```

Or

```
 $business->clients()->save($client);
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty broad guess, but your problem likely lies on `Client::create()` in your `ClientsController.php`. This line is attempting to create a client row in your database table. If your `$clientinfo` array doesn't contain a `business_id` column then the database constraint will fail owing to the missing value.

Comment: Does the 'businesses' table exist? Is the date used as the prefix of the migration file a date prior to that of the `clients` table? In other words, was `businesses` table created before `clients`? Also, on separate note, check and make sure that the table is actually called `businesses` and not `businesss`. It might be a lot easier to `migrate:rollback` and then do a fresh `migrate` or a `migrate:fresh`.

Comment: @marcus.ramsden Thanks! The line $clientinfo = Request::all();  doesn't return business_id because this data from a form that the user filled out to add a new client. That's why i'm populating it myself with this line : $client->business_id = Auth::user()->business_id;  Not sure if it's the right way to do it though. Should I add the business_id value in a input "hidden" in my form on my create page? Thanks again!

Comment: @CrackingTheCode Thanks CTC, I totally understand what you mean, I had to figure that out the other day. Yes, my businesses table exist and I have a row with an ID = 7 in it. I went through the name 5 times, maybe i'm just getting tired. Thanks !

Comment: @user3489502 yep you will want to either add the business Id to the form in a hidden field or if you want to keep that detail hidden from the user for any reason then add it to the input array before you create the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both following are correct ways, but first one is more Laravel than later,

```
public function store(ClientsRequest $request)
{
    $client = new Client([
        'first_name' => $request->get('first_name'),
        'last_name'  => $request->get('last_name'),
    ]);

    $client = Business::findOrFail(Auth::user()->business_id)
              ->clients()
              ->save($client);

    return redirect('clients/'.$client->id.'/edit');
}
```

P.S.  above `business_id` will be automatically added to `client` by `Eloquent`

Other way is like you did, where you are inserting a `business_id` manually.

```
public function store(ClientsRequest $request)
{
    $clientinfo = Request::all();

    $client = Client::create([
    'business_id' => Auth::user()->business_id;
    'first_name' => $clientinfo['first_name'];
    'last_name' => $clientinfo['last_name'];
    ]);

    return redirect('clients/'.$client->id.'/edit');
}
```

You are receiving error because of following statement in your code,

```
Client::create($clientinfo);
```

Above statement will attempt to create a database entry without `business_id` which is a foreign key and should be supplied but wasn't and hence error.

And you don't have to worry about type-conversion between int<->string, PHP is very good at it.

[Read More](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

Comment: Thanks, I see that I was mixing the syntax. I went with your first example. Works perfectly. That's my problem, I know what I want, but can't get the syntax right. Thanks again